# Cannot Check-In changes to TFS since migrating to 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tfs, tfs-2015

Since the upgrade to TFS 2015, I am unable to link work items when checking in a new piece of work using Visual Studio 2008.

When selecting a work item to link I get the following error message:
"Value does not fall within the expected range."

Before the upgrade to TFS 2015 I did not have this problem and Check-In's worked correctly.

As a work around I am able to Check-In some changes by not linking to a work item and then by viewing the work item inside TFS I can then link the bug backwards to the associated change set.

Does anyone know why I can no longer link work items since the 2015 upgrade and what I can do to fix the issue?

Comment: have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/TFS/administer/requirements?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  towards the bottom you'll see Client Compatibility.  Apparently you'll need the MSSCCI provider...

Comment: I have tried installing the "MSSCCI Provider" but I still have the same issue.  When launching Visual Studio I get an error message: "Team Foundation Error - Specified method is not supported"

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to update your VS2008 to VS2015. Or you can try below method:
 Close Visual Studio and clear VS cache, then restart it.

Comment: Clearing cache alone won't help. Also, if you are bound to VS2008, updating to a newer version isn't an option either.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bound to Visual Studio 2008 eg. if you are developing for WindowsCE, make sure you're running VS2008 SP1 then try installing MSSCCI Provier.

[MSSCCI Provider 32bit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M)

If this doesn't help, also install Compatibility GDR

[Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Compatibility GDR](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29983)

After also [deleting the local TFS Cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsalm/2013/12/17/how-to-clear-the-tfs-cache-on-client-machines/), i was able to Check-In/Check-Out with linked Items on TFS2017. Only thing that doesn't work until now, is listing builds and build definitions. This will result in the message "Specified method is not supported" every time you connect to the TFS or refresh the Builds.